# email image not displaying in gmail

Tags: laravel, email, gmail, spam

I try to send email with image ,but in gmail not showing my image and remove attribute src from image

> My code image

```
<img src="{{asset('icon.png')}}" alt="logo" title="Logo" style="display:block"  width="60" height="60"/>
```

> the code in gmail

```
<img alt="Logo" title="Logo" style="display:block" width="60" height="60">
```

Comment: Does gmail show a button or link somewhere that reads something like "show images"? It might be hiding images that are loaded from an external website if the sender has a low reputation or the message looks like it could be spam

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel's Documention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#inline-attachments), try this:

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed('assets/icon.png')) }}" alt="logo" title="Logo" style="display:block"  width="60" height="60"/>
```